# LG G6 recognized by ADB, but NOT by fastboot

Tags: windows-10, drivers, android

I'm trying to unlock the bootloader on my LG G6 (specifically LGUS997) phone to enable root access. Following LG's instructions, I've downloaded the command line Android SDK tools, notably ADB and fastboot.

ADB recognizes my phone just fine but in order to unlock the bootloader I need to reboot the phone into fastboot mode (which ADB can do). The problem is fastboot.exe does not recognize my phone at all, even after installing the Google USB drivers as well as my phone's specific drivers.

All of the solutions I've found online are to install the drivers I've already installed, or to enable USB debugging (which I have done).

For clarification, I'm using 64-bit Windows 10.

Comment: Restart the computer since you've installed everything and then see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

It was a driver issue for me, however I prefer to only use trustworthy sources. So:

- Download from https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb
- Plug your phone in, boot it in fastboot
- Open the Windows Driver Manager
- There should be an unknown Android device -> update drivers -> search locally -> choose from list from your computer -> Show every device -> Select the "android_winusb.inf" you just downloaded -> Select "Android Bootloader Interface" -> if warning, still contiune -> finish, now fastboot did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install this from here. I use this all the time. https://androiddatahost.com/uq6us
You won't have to do anything before/after that. Install and open it from start menu.

Comment: Still the same, all this seems to do is extract adb and fastboot (which I already have)

Comment: Did you boot your phone into fastboot mode?

Comment: Boot your device into fastboot mode then type fastboot devices

Comment: Press volume down and power button together to boot into fastboot mode. Then connect your phone with your PC. Then try.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, fastboot mode also brings up nothing when I list the devices.